# Angularjs routing issue controller not triggered after click the link ?

Tags: angularjs, angular-routing

I have implemented  the routing in our website i have properly link all the href  with controller but i don't understand why controller is not fire check my fiddle code and tell what's the wrong in my code?

```js
var app = angular.module("angularDemoApp", ["ngRoute"]);
app.config(function($routeProvider) {

$routeProvider.when('/Family', {
    templateURL : 'Family.html',
    controller  : 'familyController'
  }).when('/Friends',{
    templateURL : 'Friends.html',
    controller  : 'friendsController'
  }).when('/Photo', {  
    templateURL : 'Photo.html',
    controller  : 'photoController'
  })
})

app.controller('familyController', function($scope) {
  $scope.msg = "hiii homeee";
});
app.controller('friendsController', function($scope) {
  alert('ssss');
  $scope.friendsMsg = "hiii friendsMsg";
});
app.controller('photoController', function($scope) {
  alert('ssss');
  $scope.photoMsg = "hiii photoMsg";
})
```

```html
<ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked">
  <li>
    <a href="#/Family">Family</a>
   </li>
 <li>
    <a href="#/Friends">Friends</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#/Photos">Photos</a>
   </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using angular version above 1.6 routes changed from #/state to #!/state

DEMO

```js
var app = angular.module("angularDemoApp", ["ngRoute"])
app.config(function($routeProvider) {

$routeProvider.when('/Family', {
    template: `<h1>{{msg}}</h1>`,
    controller  : 'familyController'
  }).when('/Friends',{
    template: `<h1>{{friendsMsg}}</h1>`,
    controller  : 'friendsController'
  }).when('/Photo', {  
    template: `<h1>{{photoMsg}}</h1>`,
    controller  : 'photoController'
  })
})

app.controller('familyController', function($scope) {
  $scope.msg = "hiii homeee";
});
app.controller('friendsController', function($scope) {
  alert('ssss');
  $scope.friendsMsg = "hiii friendsMsg";
});
app.controller('photoController', function($scope) {
  alert('ssss');
  $scope.photoMsg = "hiii photoMsg";
})
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="angularDemoApp">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>AngularJS User Registration and Login Example  </title>
</head>

<body>
  
  <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked">
  <li>
    <a href="#!/Family">Family</a>
   </li>
 <li>
    <a href="#!/Friends">Friends</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#!/Photos">Photos</a>
   </li>
</ul>
  <div class="mainContainer" ng-view></div>
  <script src="//unpkg.com/angular@1.6/angular.js"></script>
  <script src="//unpkg.com/angular-route@1.6/angular-route.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: sir i tried this but again controller is not triggered ?

Comment: what do you mean by not triggered? you can see in the above demo

Comment: Ok sir  i will check

Comment: sir it is working but tell m one thing why use  template instead of the templateURL?

Comment: since i cannot load external files in the snippet i have used template instead of templateURL

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/181844/discussion-between-kapil-soni-and-sajeetharan).